# How to use string as input for csv reader without storing it to file

Tags: python, csv, stringio

I'm trying to loop through rows in a `csv` file. I get `csv` file as `string` from a web location. I know how to create `csv.reader` using `with` when data is stored in a file. What I don't know is, how to get rows using `csv.reader` without storing `string` to a file. I'm using Python 2.7.12.

I've tried to create `StringIO` object like this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

csv_data = "some_string\nfor_example"
with StringIO(csv_data) as input_file:
    csv_reader = reader(csv_data, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 228, in <module>
    with StringIO(csv_data) as input_file:
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

I understand that `StringIO` class doesn't have `__exit__` method which is called when `when` finishes doing whatever it does with this object.

My answer is how to do this correctly? I suppose I can alter `StringIO` class by subclassing it and adding `__exit__` method, but I suspect that there is easier solution.

Update:

Also, I've tried different combinations that came to my mind:

```
with open(StringIO(csv_data)) as input_file:

with csv_data as input_file:
```

but, of course, none of those worked.

Comment: Simply use `input_file = StringIO(csv_data)` instead of the `with` block.  How do you download the CSV data from the web?  You usually get a file object when downloading, which can be used directly without first storing the whole content in a string variable and then wrapping that variable in `StringIO`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Python 3.5. `StringIO` can be used in a `with`. What is *exactly* your version and the code? (`from StringIO import StringIO` is *bad*...)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, I can do it this way, but I'd like to use `with`. I'm using `requests.get` to get data, and then create `csv_data` from `response.text`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: StringIO supports the context manager interface and can be used in `with` statements...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry, forgot to mention that. I use Python 2.7.12. I've updated the question. And I use *exactly* `from StringIO import StringIO`.

Comment: @Fejs _Why_ do you want to use `with`?  It doesn't do anything useful in this case.

Comment: @Fejs: Ok I had never used StringIO.StringIO. I use io.BytesIO for 8 bit strings or io.StringIO for unicode ones. Both support the context manager interface, that's why I was surprised...

Comment: @SvenMarnach Well, it looked logical to use `with` if I tried to represent `csv_data` as a file. Now, it doesn't seem such a good idea...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> import csv
>>> csv_data = "some,string\nfor,example"
>>> result = csv.reader(csv_data.splitlines())
>>> list(result)
[['some', 'string'], ['for', 'example']]
```

Comment: This won't work if the string has linefeeds inside of quoted values

Answer (score 2):

You should use the io module instead of the StringIO one, because `io.BytesIO` for byte string or `io.StringIO` for Unicode ones both support the context manager interface and can be used in `with` statements:

```
from io import BytesIO
from csv import reader
csv_data = "some_string\nfor_example"
with BytesIO(csv_data) as input_file:
    csv_reader = reader(input_file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print row
```

Comment: I'm getting following error when I try this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 227, in <module>
    with BytesIO(race_csv_data) as input_file:
TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface`

Comment: @Fejs That means that your `race_csv_data` is a unicode string and you should use `io.StringIO` instead of `io.BytesIO` (but your example used a byte string ;-) ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you like context managers, you can use `tempfile` instead:

```
import tempfile


with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as t:
     t.write('csv_data')
     t.seek(0)
     csv_reader = reader(open(t.name), delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
```

As an advantage to pass string splitlines directly to csv reader you can write file of any size and then safely read it in csv reader without memory issues.

This file will be closed and deleted automatically